# How Can Asynchronous Function Result Be returned and Saved to firebase in AngularFire

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I have created the service below.

```
app.factory('userProfileFactory', ['FBDB', 'searchParam', function(FBDB, searchParam) {
        var personalKey;
    return {

        userProfile: function(searchEmail) {
          var deferred = $q.defer();
          var FBref = new Firebase(FBDB).child('items');
          var promise = FBref.orderByChild('email')
                .startAt(searchEmail)
                .endAt(searchEmail)
                .on('value', function(snapshot) {
                  var data = snapshot.val();
                  personalKey = Object.keys(data)[0];
                  deferred.resolve(personalKey);
                });
          return deferred.promise;
        }
    };
}]);
```

My Controller is as below. The issue is that it takes a moment for results to be returned. So when the $save function is called outside factory function, it reports an 'undefined variable'. How can I make it work when $save is outside?

```
app.controller('profileCtrl', ['userProfileFactory', 'FBDB', '$firebaseArray', function(userProfileFactory, FBDB, $firebaseArray) {

var FBref = new Firebase(FBDB).child('items');

     userProfileFactory.userProfile().then(function(res){
         var personalKey = res;

        item.personalKey = res;

        //$firebaseArray(FBref)$save(item);  It works here. But moved this from here... 
    })

     $firebaseArray(FBref)$save(item); //...to here. It does not work.

}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the line:

```
$firebaseArray(FBref)$save(item);
```

will execute before the resolve function:

```
function(res){
     var personalKey = res;

    item.personalKey = res;
}
```

The resolve function waits for the userProfileFactory.userProfile() promise to resolve (data to be returned) before executing, whereas the firebase.save line does not.  You need to put it back inside of the then(resolve) function.